# OTA InitConnectionEx, Login -> Exception: ServerThread DB_TIME_COUNT=

Tags: alm

I'm having a c# application which uses OTA-Com-Library to login to ALM. Every time I try to login I get the following exception:

```
{"<ServerThread DB_TIME_COUNT=\"0\" DB_TIME_MAX=\"0\" SERVER_MACHINE_NAME=\"GRZWINSV1371\" DB_TIME_MIN=\"0\" PROJECT=\"N/A\" THREAD_ID=\"62ED8023-E88C-4CCE-85C0-DFE7D0B108B7\" FS_TIME_MIN=\"0\" SERVER_START_TIME_MS=\"1462181946133\" SERVER_TOTAL_TIME=\"2\" FS_TIME_AVG=\"0\" THREAD_TYPE=\"Login\" SERVER_CPU_TIME=\"0\" FS_TIME_MAX=\"0\" USER_NAME=\"N/A\" FS_TIME_COUNT=\"0\" PROJECT_SESSION_ID=\"-1\" LOGIN_SESSION_ID=\"-1\" THREAD_CATEGORY=\"FREC_REQUEST_CALL\" SERVER_START_TIME=\"2016-05-02 11:39:06\" DB_TIME_AVG=\"0\" />"}
```

This is the c# code:

```
  try
        {
            this.server = server;
            this.username = user;
            this.pwd = password;

            tdConn.InitConnectionEx(server);
            tdConn.Login(user, password);                               
        }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        ExceptionUtils.ReportHandledException(exception);
    }
```

I registered the COM Components by using "Register HP ALM" of provided on this site:

https://centre.qualitat.solucions.gencat.cat/qcbin/CommonMode_index.html

Cheers,
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

Ensure url spesified correctly.
 URL to init OTA connection need to be specified in format: `http://<server_host>:<server_port>/qcbin`

The message you specified comes from server, but not looks like exception.
Please specify full exception with stack trace. Additional information could be obtained from WebGate log. To turn it on follow instruction:

1. Go to your server apps: https://centre.qualitat.solucions.gencat.cat/qcbin/Apps/
2. Click "Client Logs Configuration Tool"
3. When tool downloads run it
4. Go to the "WebGate" section
5. For "Log Level" choose "ALL - Log everything" and specify the path wehere log should write to.

Then reproduce the problem and observe WebGate log at path specified and look for text highlighted with red or just provide the output adter "Login Started:" and before "Login Ended:" in the log file.